# Unable to get ApplicationInsights to trace

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

I've created a new Azure Web job, a new Application Insights resource, and am simply trying to get one to log to the other.  As I understand it, it should be as straight-forward as adding the appropriate NuGet packages, and adding some code along these lines:

```
TelemetryClient tc = new TelemetryClient();
tc.InstrumentationKey = "my-key";
tc.TrackEvent("testing");
tc.TrackTrace("test diag");
tc.Flush();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

The sleep is there because I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-windows-desktop) MS article that suggested it might be needed.  This code happens as the web job fires up (so effectively, it's just a console app).  However, when I run it, I get no metrics whatsoever.

I've tried putting the key in the `ApplicationInsights.config`, but that makes no difference.  I've also tried different types of logging, including exceptions.

My guess is that the code above isn't doing what I think it is, but I'd be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction as to why.

Comment: Are you checking the events/traces directly? They are probably pushed to AppInsights, but not handled directly. I've seen delays of more then 10 minutes before statistics appeared in the portal. So it might be a good idea to check back later on.

Comment: Yes - I've left it overnight.  And it depends what you mean by "checking directly" - I'm checking them via the portal using Analytics.

Answer (score 1):

I can [track user events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics) by inserting TrackEvent calls in Azure Webjobs function code, the following sample works fine on my side, you can refer to it.

**packages.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" version="2.4.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept" version="2.4.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector" version="2.4.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector" version="2.4.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer" version="2.4.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel" version="2.4.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.7.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.7.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.7.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow" version="4.5.24" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager" version="3.2.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="ncrontab" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.7.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="7.2.1" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;

namespace WebJob1
{
    // To learn more about Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK, please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320976
    class Program
    {
        // Please set the following connection strings in app.config for this WebJob to run:
        // AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage
        static void Main()
        {
            var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

            TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";

            new TelemetryClient().TrackEvent("WebJobStart", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "appInsightsInstrumentationKey", TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey } });

            config.DashboardConnectionString = "";
            config.UseTimers();


            var host = new JobHost(config);
            // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
            host.RunAndBlock();
        }
    }
}
```

**Functions.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

namespace WebJob1
{
    public class Functions
    {
        public static void TimerJob([TimerTrigger("00:01:00")] TimerInfo timerInfo, TextWriter log)
        {
            new TelemetryClient().TrackEvent("testing "+ DateTime.UtcNow.ToShortDateString(), new Dictionary<string, string> { { "appInsightsInstrumentationKey", TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey } });

            log.WriteLine("Process Something called at : " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Events in the Azure portal**

[image]